# Why different tenses?

Tags: verbs, tenses, ing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using verb tenses correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43056/using-verb-tenses-correctly)

This is a quote from *The Great Gatsby*:

> She smiled slowly and, walking through her husband as if he were a ghost, shook hands with Tom, looking him flush in the eye!

Why do these four verbs have different tenses: *smiled, walking, shook, looking*?

Comment: +1 for use of '-ing form'. This form implies aspect, not tense.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm a newbie,could you help me edit the question?

Comment: What did you mean by “tense” back when you first asked the question? Also, you forgot about *were*.

Comment: @tchrist Actually I was not sure how to explain it,just wanted to know why they are different.

Comment: Happy to. Your original title indicated that what you were confused about was the forms using '-ing', so I've reverted to your original title (which is what I was praising you for: '+1' means I upvoted your question precisely because you talked about 'form' rather than 'tense'). I did change 'haze' to 'hazy' because I think you meant *you* are confused, not that there is a general confusionAnd I changed your question to focus on what I take to be your concern: why the '-ing' form is used and what it means. - I'm not sure when you'll see my edits - this is the first time I've edited a question.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you,and you sound like a psychologist :)

Answer (score 4):

The question is incorrect because it makes the wrong [Presuppositions](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Presuppositiontriggers.pdf).

> Why do the four verbs here (*smiled, walking, shook, looking*) have different tenses?

They **don't** have different tenses, you see. And there are **five** verbs in that sentence.

*Smiled* and *shook* are indeed both ***Past Tense***, but *walking* and *looking* aren't **any** tense at all. *Walking* and *looking* are ***Participles*** (in both cases the ***Present Active Partiple***, or
[***-ing*** Form](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gerund.html), of the verb), which, like ***Infinitives***, are not inflected for tense, or anything else.

Each of these participles heads a Participial Clause, which is usually  derived ultimately from a field-stripped relative or, as in this case, adverbial clause.

- ***(after/while she)** walked through her husband as if he were a ghost*
- ***(as/while/at the same time she)** looked him  flush in the eye*

They are participle clauses instead of tensed clauses because they lend a sense of immediacy and simultaneity to a description of a physical action, making the reader reconstruct the event more as a movie than a set of flat pictures. Note the alternation of the tensed and the untensed actions, like camera shots. For future analysis, [this summary](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf) may be of some assistance.

As to the missed verb, it's *were* in the idiomatic tensed adverb clause  *as if he **were** a ghost.*

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself: "the ***Present*** Active Participle ... not inflected for tense" There are two participle forms in English.

Comment: That's a **name** of the inflection, not its **description**. Would you have preferred the official formal name, which is ***{-ING}***? I'm attempting to avoid overformalism here, but to do that one must depend on cooperation rather than peeving. There are indeed two participial forms; the other is ***{-EN₁}***, often called "Past Participle", or "Perfect Passive Participle". I've often regretted the profusion of polysyllabic P's in grammatical terms.

Comment: Ok,I have modified the question as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'll show you how three of the verbs are used. If we changed all of them into the same tense, past simple, this is what would happen:

> She **smiled** slowly, **shook** hands with Tom, and **looked** him
>   flush in the eye.

Do you notice the change? The actions would become a sequence if we changed them all in the same tense.

So:

> She **smiled**, **shook** hands with Tom, **looking** him flush in the
>   eye.

The act of "*looking*" happened more or less at the same time as "*shaking hands*."

---

Now, to explain the verb "*walking*," this is what we call an **+ing clause**. It derives from the original, complete prepositional clause, "*after she walked through her husband*" and can also be rephrased as "*having walked through her husband*" to state the actual order of the actions.

But because "*walk*" is a short action followed by another short action "*shake hands*," we can simply use the **v+ing** instead of having p.p. Like this:

> **Walking** through her husband as if he were a ghost, she shook hands with Tom.

Answer (score 1):

The words "smiled" and "shook" are simple past tenses and indicate an action that is completed.  The other two -ing verbs are used to show a continuing action.  See [What verb tense describes continuing action?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_verb_tense_describes_continuing_action)