# Is this sentence using tenses correctly?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, tenses

> If such stage was completed based on un-signed English financial statements (USEFS), the doer is to initial all pages of the USEFS.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct with two different tenses?
I have argued with my friend that the above sentence was wrong as the tenses used were different: "the if tense is in the past while the second part is in the present" and the sentence in this form would be awkward for English native speakers.

Comment: This just looks like proofreading to me. Voting to close as Too Localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think the sentence is correct and we may understand it as an example of the problem which OP feels (mistakenly, in my opinion) it exhibits.

Comment: @StoneyB: What "real-world" problem does this represent? If OP is attempting to *write* this kind of legalese, I want no part of it. If he's hoping we'll agree he's found an error in his contract, again, I don't want to be involved. If he just wants to know whether the two tenses are correct in such constructions, he could have presented a more sensible example, such as *"If you **did** A, you **are to do** B"*.

Comment: ...(which, after scrolling down, I see you have effectively paraphrased yourself! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  On this argument, we must ban as Too Localised **any** question which includes **any** example, whether from Milton or Microsoft or Maureen Dowd. The example is Local; the question is General.

Comment: @StoneyB: That's taking my position to ridiculous extremes. The specific "verb tense" issue involved here is so trivial it would probably have been closed straight away if it had simply asked whether "If you did A, you are to do B" was correct. As Barrie points out, OP's version is "an unhappy sentence altogether", which frankly I have trouble believing any native speaker (even a dyed-in-the-wool legalese aficionado) would come out with. I think it debases the site to pointlessly mix obfuscating context with trivial points of grammar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using verb tenses correctly](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43056/using-verb-tenses-correctly)

Answer (score 4):

Your example sentence is proper. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence), a sentence of the type called the *first conditional* is used

> to express a hypothetical condition that is potentially true, but not yet verified. The conditional clause is in the present or past tense and refers to a state or event in the past. The result can be in the past, present, or future.

Think of your example as equivalent to

> If you **did** that yesterday, you must now **do** this today.

Obviously you cannot cast both clauses in the same tense here.

Answer (score 0):

It’s an unhappy sentence altogether. You can at least get round any problem of verb forms by substituting *must* for *is to* in the main clause.